# JSX: difference between two JSX sets

Tags: javascript, set, jsx

If I declare

```
 var A = new Set(...........);
 var B = new Set(...........);
```

is there a JSX operation to calculate the difference of two sets A - B?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this is related to JSX, but there is a `difference` method implementation published on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
var difference = new Set([...A].filter(x => !B.has(x)));
```

Though modifying the prototypes of built-ins is not recommended, you could also (from that same MDN link) add `difference` to the `Set` prototype:

```
Set.prototype.difference = function(setB) {
    var difference = new Set(this);
    for (var elem of setB) {
        difference.delete(elem);
    }
    return difference;
}

var A = new Set(...........);
var B = new Set(...........);
console.log(A.difference(B))
```